# Exclude subdirectory from WordPress redirection

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to redirect all visitors to my WordPress website except the translations available for pages in the `/cy/` subdirectory:

- `/cy/`

so for example

- `https://myoldomain.co.uk/cy/partners/`

is not redirected but

- `https://myoldomain.co.uk/partners/`
- `https://myoldomain.co.uk/`

are redirected.

I have tried lots and this one works in an online tester but not in practice - all domains including those with `/cy/` are redirected.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} myoldomain\.co.uk
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(cy|cy/.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mynewdomain\.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: "all **domains** including those with `/cy/` are..." - presumably you mean "URLs"?

Comment: Sorry yes - I mean urls. (Too long staring at my screen.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} myoldomain\.co.uk
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(cy|cy/.*)$ 
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mynewdomain\.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

If you are using WordPress then you have a front-controller pattern later in the file that rewrites all non-files to `index.php` (the WP front-controller). During the *second pass* of the rewrite engine `/index.php` is obvsiously not `/cy...` so the redirect occurs. But this should be visible in the redirect.

You need to make sure the above redirect only applies to the initial request from the client and not the rewritten request. You can do this by checking against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable (which is empty on the initial request).

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (^|\.)myoldomain\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(cy|cy/.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mynewdomain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And this needs to go near the top of the file, *before* the WP front-controller pattern.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing. Preferably test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be pretty but appears to  Exclude wp-login.php and the wp admin area from the redirect.

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (^|\.)myoldomain\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(cy|cy/.*)$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(wp-admin|wp-admin/.*)$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(wp-includes|wp-includes/.*)$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(wp-content|wp-content/.*)$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-login.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mynewdomain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Minor point, but something like `!^/(wp-includes|wp-includes/.*)$` can be reduced to `!^/wp-includes($|/)` - which avoids repetition and is marginally more optimal (since it doesn't need to traverse the entire URL-path).